# Django - cannot assign - must be an instance

Tags: django, model, extend

I tried phrasing this question recently and got totally confused.  I've extended the default user model with this in my models.py:

```
class Biography(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    biography = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True,default='Details')
```

I've included this in the forms.py:

```
class EditProfileForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(label='First Name')
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Last Name')
    biography = forms.CharField(label='Biography', widget=Textarea(attrs={'rows': 5}))
```

I have a view to edit the profile and want to add "biography" to it, but have absolutely no clue where to start.  Here's the view:

```
def edit_profile(request):
    user = request.user
    products = Product.objects.filter(user=user)
    form = EditProfileForm(request.POST or None, initial={'first_name':user.first_name, 'last_name':user.last_name})
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            user.first_name = request.POST['first_name']
            user.last_name = request.POST['last_name']
            user.save()
            return render(request, 'profile.html', {'user':user, 'products':products})
    context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, "edit_profile.html", context)
```

I tried to replicate what is already there with this:

```
def edit_profile(request):
    user = request.user
    products = Product.objects.filter(user=user)
    biography = Biography(user=user)
    form = EditProfileForm(request.POST or None, initial={'first_name':user.first_name, 'last_name':user.last_name, 'biography':user.biography})
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            user.first_name = request.POST['first_name']
            user.last_name = request.POST['last_name']
            user.biography = request.POST['biography']
            user.save()
            return render(request, 'profile.html', {'user':user, 'products':products})
    context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, "edit_profile.html", context)
```

I definitely missed the point somehow.  The last time I asked this question I was somewhat chastised for not knowing how to solve it.  In all honesty I'm really new to Django and am amazed I got this far, but I'm stuck.  I 'think' I need to create an instance but am not sure how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do differently:

1. Create `Biography` instance if it does not exist, or get from db.
2. Instantiate separate forms for different request methods
3. Use `cleaned_data` as input validation is one of the main purposes of forms
4. Always redirect after POST
5. Save `User` and `Biography` instances separately
6. And you don't need related `products` in form view. If only you are not going to somehow update them here.

For example:

```
def edit_profile(request):
    user = request.user
    biography, created = Biography.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    form = EditProfileForm(initial={
        'first_name': user.first_name,
        'last_name': user.last_name,
        'biography': biography.biography
    })

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditProfileForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user.first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']  # use cleaned_data
            user.last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            biography.biography = form.cleaned_data['biography']
            biography.save()  # save Biography object
            user.save()  # save User object
            return redirect(biography)  #  always redirect after successful POST. In this case Biography must have get_absolute_url() method

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'edit_profile.html', context)
```

Read more in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#the-view).

Comment: I see how this works now - thank you.  There is one issue - I get the error `AttributeError at /profile/edit/
'tuple' object has no attribute 'biography'` - the highlighted text on the error page is `'biography': biography.biography` - I'm looking through documentation on that now.

Comment: @Steve Can you post full traceback somewhere? Looks like you're getting a tuple instead of Biography object.

Comment: So far I changed `biography = Biography.objects.get_or_create(user=user)` to `biography, created = Biography.objects.get_or_create(user=user)` - now it works.  I see this input reflected in the admin panel too.  I'm using `<p>Biography: {{ user.biography.biography }}</p>` to display the input - hopefully I haven't broken any rules, but it seems fixed.  Couldn't do that without your help though.  If you edit the code above I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Ah, sure. Forgot it returns tuple, thanks for that. Edited the code in answer. And it's OK to use `{{ user.biography.biography }}` to display a related object.

Answer (score 0):

`user.biography` is an instance of `Biography` model, so what you should do here is get that instance and edit its attributes, like this:

```
bio = user.biography
bio.biography = request.POST['biography']
bio.save()
```